# How to make a sprite jump up and return to original position GDXLib

Tags: java, android, sprite

I'm very new to programming so bear with me here...

I'm making a basic 2d android game. I am trying to simply make a sprite jump up in the air a bit and then land back to where it originally started. The sprite that I want to jump is "ball2". This is my code so far (Basically just added textures and the sprite in the correct position to start the jump but haven't done anything else).

Any help is appreciated.

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture background;
Texture ball;
Texture spike1;
Texture spike2;


@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    background = new Texture("gamebackground.png");

    ball = new Texture("ball2.png");
    ball.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);

    spike1 = new Texture("spike1.png");
    spike1.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);
    spike2 = new Texture("spike2.png");

}

@Override
public void render () {

    batch.begin();
    float scaleFactor = 2.0f;
    batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.draw(ball, 80, 145, ball.getWidth() * scaleFactor, ball.getHeight() * scaleFactor);
    batch.end();

}
```

Comment: So, flappybird basically? You could set a listener for click and when they click increase height over a short duration and set their height down at a constant rate every second.

Comment: Would that make the ball return to the position it started at? I don't want it to drop down using gravity like in flappybird but just back to where it was to begin with if you get what I mean?

Comment: Ah, okay. Then just set height +50 or whatever you want then have a timer and after it hits a certain time set height back to the original. I'd probably avoid -50 as sometimes code is finicky and it may cause a slight bug.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dumb but could you show an example of how to do that? Just as a guideline because I've literally just started to learn how to program haha!

Comment: I'll just submit this as an answer cause it won't fit here.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void render () {

    batch.begin();
    float scaleFactor = 2.0f;
    batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.draw(ball, 80, 145, ball.getWidth() * scaleFactor, ball.getHeight() * scaleFactor);
    batch.end();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter () {
            @Override
               public boolean keyDown (int keycode) {
                if(keycode==Keys.UP)
                {
                   ball.setHeight(ball.getHeight()+50);
                }
                return true;
               }  
    }


}
```

Then you need to add the timer down down or you could add down button. Not sure if you have spikes on the top as well. I don't know what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: Seems mostly to be fine except the "setHeight" is shown as error "cannot resolve method"?

Comment: Well with your method you aren't creating anything so it's hard to redraw since there isn't an object to move. You could refresh everything, getting rid of that ball and then redraw an equal ball above it?

clear

batch.draw(ball, 80, 95, ball.getWidth() * scaleFactor, ball.getHeight() * scaleFactor);

wait 5

then:

batch.draw(ball, 80, 145, ball.getWidth() * scaleFactor, ball.getHeight() * scaleFactor);